# HTML tags for groups in PHP array

Tags: php, html, arrays

Borrowing from someone else's question

I have an array

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 95,
        [shipping_no] => 212755-1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 96,
        [shipping_no] => 212755-1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 97,
        [shipping_no] => 212755-2
    )

)`
```

I need to output so it appears

```
<div class="shipping-no">
 Shipping No: 212755-1
 ID: 95
 ID: 96
</div>
<div class="shipping-no">
 Shipping No: 212755-2
 ID: 97
</div>
```

The ordering is fine, using `foreach` to step through. The 'problem' I have is that the test for whether the shipping number is the same as the last one happens at the top of each iteration so that I have the first line of the iteration as `if ($last_shipping_no != $this_shipping_no) { echo '</div><div class="shipping-no">' }`

This seems clumsy to me, also I have to write the first opening tag before the loop and the last closing tag after the loop.

What is the elegant way of doing this?

Comment: are there need to output data in <div> with line breaks?

Comment: the data should be grouped before iterating to display them. It feels like this data is coming from the database and it can be grouped by shipping_no. Regardless, I think you should do this grouping in your php code before generating html.

Comment: Grouping before sounds good. How do I do this? And how does the foreach work then - do I need to nest loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @davicompu proposed, I would go with re-indexing the data based on the unique identifier. In this case it seems to be the `shipping_no`. This can be done with a simple `foreach` as follows:

```
$indexed = array();
foreach ($shippings as $s) {
    # if the key does not exist create it
    if (!isset($indexed, $s["shipping_no"])) {
        $indexed[$s["shipping_no"]] = array();
        $indexed[$s["shipping_no"]]["ids"] = array();
    }

    # In any case append the ID
    $indexed[$s["shipping_no"]]["ids"][] = $s["id"];
}
```

The result looks like:

```
array(2) {
  ["212755-1"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["ids"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(95)
      [1]=>
      int(96)
    }
  }
  ["212755-2"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["ids"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(97)
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, shipping orders are indexed by the unique identifier into the array. Each one has an array/list id IDs. This allows for future expansion ie adding new attributes to `shippings` without changing your data structure.

The printing code then becomes trivial:

```
foreach ($indexed as $k=>$v) {
    # Open the shipping-no div
    print("<div class='shipping-no'>\n");

    # Print shipping attributes
    print("Shifting No: $k\n");

    # Loop and print its IDs
    foreach ($v["ids"] as $id) {
        print("ID: $id\n");
    }

    # Close the shipping-no div
    print("</div>\n");
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This looks like the way to go (apart from doing the same in SQL) - I shall study. At the moment it's a little above my pay grade but that's the way I like it. Thank you .

Comment: If you load this data from a SQL database you can also implement a [Database Abstraction Layer (DAL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_abstraction_layer) or use some sort of ORM to do the job for you (depending on the number of tables you are working with ORM might be overkill - example http://propelorm.org/)

Comment: Just to note for anyone walking this way (because it took me a while to work out) ; in the real world, obviously 'id' would be one value in another  array so you load the array into this code `$indexed[$s["shipping_no"]]["ids"][] = $s;` then in the print use `$id['id'], $id['some_other_key']` etc to access the values

Answer (score 0):

```
if(count($array) == count(array_unique($array))){ 
  //shipping-no is unique 
}else{ 
  echo 'The following Shipping-no are not unique:'; 
  var_dump(array_diff($array,array_unique($array))); 

 // here you search about The key that are not unique with for or foreach 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do a mvc approach I wil suggest you first make a dictonary with the data.

It could be a dictonary having the shipping_no as key and value array of ids.

It is recommended that your take as much as you can the business logic from your view. So if you refractor you incoming data (array), you will have not to worry how to display it, I mean at least not having to use php mixed with html.

Comment: Sorry! That went straight over my head (although I understand what you're saying) - can you point at a resource where I can learn about this ?

Comment: Sure thing Chris, there are plenty out there but you can use this one http://requiremind.com/a-most-simple-php-mvc-beginners-tutorial/. Any mvc explanation will work the one I'm sharing with you has php on it

Answer (score 0):

Unified solution for more complex situations when there's array with unordered elements:

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        'id' => 98,
        'shipping_no' => '212755-2'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 95,
        'shipping_no' => '212755-1'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 96,
        'shipping_no' => '212755-1'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 97,
        'shipping_no' => '212755-2'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 99,
        'shipping_no' => '212755-3'
    )
);

uasort($arr, function($a,$b){
    return ($a['shipping_no'] < $b['shipping_no'])? -1 : (($a['shipping_no'] > $b['shipping_no'])? 1 : 0);     
});

$result = [];
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    if (!isset($result[$value['shipping_no']])){
        $result[$value['shipping_no']] = [$value['id']];
    } else {
        $result[$value['shipping_no']][] = $value['id'];
    }
    sort($result[$value['shipping_no']], SORT_NUMERIC);
}

foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    $ids = (count($value) > 1)? implode("<br>ID: ", $value) : $value[0];
    echo '<div class="shipping-no">'.
        "Shipping No: $key <br> ID: ". $ids;
}
```

```html
<div class="shipping-no">Shipping No: 212755-1 <br> ID: 95<br>ID: 96<div class="shipping-no">Shipping No: 212755-2 <br> ID: 97<br>ID: 98<div class="shipping-no">Shipping No: 212755-3 <br> ID: 99
```